# Vue 3 - 'this' is unreachable / 'this' targets the wrong section

Tags: javascript, this, vuejs3

In Vue 3, I'm trying to target a property in the `data()` function from within a nested function in the `mounted()` hook.  Here's my code example:

```js
export default defineComponent({
    components: {
        ProgressTable
    },
    name: 'Sidebar',
    emits: ['remove-sidebar'],
    data () {
        return {
            userData: authStore.state,
            trackedSymptoms: []
        };
    },
    props: {

    },
    mounted () {
        const url = '...';
        const action = 'Progress-Tracking';
        const dispensaryId = this.userData.userData.dispensaryId;
        const customerId = this.userData.userData.customerId;
        const token = localStorage.getItem('jwt');

        const params = {
            action: action,
            dispensaryId: dispensaryId,
            customerId: customerId,
            token: token
        };

        axios({
            method: 'get',
            url: url,
            params: params,
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
            }
        })
            .then(function (response) {
                this.trackedSymptoms = response.data.symptomTracking;
                console.log(response);
            })
            .catch(function (error) {
                console.log(error);
            });
    }
});
```

In the Axios code, this line:

`this.trackedSymptoms = response.data.symptomTracking;`

How can I target the `trackedSymptoms: []` instead of targeting the function that the above line is located in?

Comment: Use an arrow function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using arrow function is the fastest way to solve the problem, here's why...

`function(){}` and `()=>{}` are **not** the same thing. In many cases they behave the same way and the difference is not noticeable. `function(){}` however changes the context of `this`, whereas `()=>{}` keeps `this` in the correct context. There are times when you want the instance to change (like defining methods of the class-based component).

The arrow function is an ES6 feature that needs to be compiled the es5 and if that's not available to you and you need to support older browsers, you can manually bind the value of this with `.bind(this)` like so:

```js
    mounted () {
        //...

        axios({
            method: 'get',
            url: url,
            params: params,
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
            }
        })
            .then(function (response) {
                this.trackedSymptoms = response.data.symptomTracking;
                console.log(response);
            }.bind(this))
            .catch(function (error) {
                console.log(error);
            }.bind(this));
    }
```

As an aside, notice how `mounted ()` is defined. this is the equivalent of `mounted: function()`, if you were to switch it to `mounted: () =>` it would break, because `this` would not resolve correctly.

Additional reading

> A function's this keyword behaves a little differently in JavaScript compared to other languages. It also has some differences between strict mode and non-strict mode
> ... [src](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this)

Answer (score 1):

You can replace the anonymous function with an arrow function to not override `this`:

```
.then((response) => {
     this.trackedSymptoms = response.data.symptomTracking;
     console.log(response);
})
```